# WCF - Binding.ReceiveTimeout & ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout

Tags: .net, wcf, reliablesession

I am trying to make a WCF service which uses callbacks to the client. I would like the channel to be kept open as long as there is a connection (internet, network) and either the client or channel have not explicitly closed the channel.

In order to keep the channel open (even without activity) I found the reliable sessions that WCF supports. I see that by using reliable sessions, there are two timers which one needs to take into consideration: the `Binding.ReceiveTimeout` and the `ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout`.

After searching on the internet, I am still unable to understand exactly how these two work together. I know that if either of the two times out, the connection goes into faulted state.

My first question: What exactly happens when reliable sessions are enable?

My second question: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx), why does msdn say the following?

> Since the connection is dropped if either inactivity timer fires,
>   increasing InactivityTimeout once it is greater than ReceiveTimeout
>   has no effect. The default for both of these timeouts is 10 minutes,
>   so you always have to increase both of them to make a difference when
>   using a reliable session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an answer for your first question, have a look at the nice answer to this question:

[What is the purpose of WCF reliable session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911221/what-is-the-purpose-of-wcf-reliable-session)

To my the explanation on the msdn site is clear:
When the time specified in ReceiveTimeout(for example 10 minutes) is reached, it will end the connection, even if the reliable session has a keep alive beeing sent (for example every 1 minute).

The keep alive beeing sent every minute would make sure the inactivityTimout (for example 5 minutes) is never reached -therefor the channel would be kept open endlessly-, but after the time speciefied in ReceiveTimeout the session/channel still will be closed.

So ReceiveTimeout should always be higher or the same as inactivityTimeout, as far as I understand.

Comment: do you know how I can specify the time between keep alives? or does WCF set that internally depending on the InactivityTimeout value?

Comment: I don't know when or how keep alives are sent. I guess they would be sent if the the caller would still wait for an answer or the wcf-service would wait for the caller to send an ack. As those are 'only' control messages, I guess you should not have to deal with them at all. and anyway, if you not send a 'real'-request, the connection would still time out.

Comment: ok now i get what the reliable sessions are all about and also explains the principles behind some of the other articles i read on the subject. thanks! :)